# How show/hide icon of GPS on Status Bar?

Tags: android, gps, android-notification-bar

I want **show/hide** an icon of `gps` on `status bar` in my app if `GPS` enable/disable (The same icon of `Wifi`).

I want look GPS enable or disable while my app is running.

Comment: You need to have an icon to enable and disable GPS in your application. Is this your question? Sorry, it isn't much clear

Comment: @AnhSirk Dasarp : Yes, But I want put it on Status Bar

Comment: Doesn't it come on automatically? Eithor ways You should look into Notification Manager.

Comment: "I want show/hide an icon of gps on status bar in my app if GPS enable/disable (The same icon of Wifi)" -- this happens automatically by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

It would be on the wrong side, and it would make an entry in the pull-down menu, but you could create an ongoing notification that would display an icon (although it wouldn't be animated) until you tell it to stop.